# Replace HTML content using javaScript function onclick div?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the below snippet, which will output **HTML**, but I want texts *A0100* and *A0102* as combined string

```js
function closespan(val) {
  var parent = val.parentElement;
  parent.parentElement.removeChild(parent);
  var valHTML = document.getElementById("lblshowselected").innerHTML;
  var valSPLIT = valHTML.replace(/<img src="images\/delete.png" height="10">/, ",");
  var valTEXT = valSPLIT.innerText;
}
```

```html
<div runat="server" id="lblshowselected">
  <div class="tknz-token">A0100<span class="tknz-token-x" onclick="closespan(this);"><img src="images/delete.png" height="10"></span></div>
  <div class="tknz-token">A0102<span class="tknz-token-x" onclick="closespan(this);"><img src="images/delete.png" height="10"></span></div>
</div>
```

Output
valHTML : `"<div class="tknz-token">A0100<span class="tknz-token-x" onclick="closespan(this);"><img src="images/delete.png" height="10"></span></div><div class="tknz-token">A0102<span class="tknz-token-x" onclick="closespan(this);"><img src="images/delete.png" height="10"></span></div>"`

Expected Output

> A0100,A0102

Comment: What do you want?

Comment: i want valtext value like  A0100 , A0102  form

Comment: @aparnarai do you want combined string like **"A0100, A0102"**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the `tknz-token` elements using `getElementsByClassName()` and iterate to get push `textContent` in an array.

Here is an example, I have only added code to get the `textContent`.

```js
function closespan(val) {
  //Modified code
  var lbl = document.getElementById("lblshowselected");
  var arr = [];
  var tokens = lbl.getElementsByClassName('tknz-token');
  for (var i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    arr.push(tokens[i].textContent);
  }
  console.log(arr.join(','));
}
```

```html
<div runat="server" id="lblshowselected">
  <div class="tknz-token">A0100<span class="tknz-token-x" onclick="closespan(this);"><img src="images/delete.png" height="10"></span></div>
  <div class="tknz-token">A0102<span class="tknz-token-x" onclick="closespan(this);"><img src="images/delete.png" height="10"></span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add your text as HTML instead of normal Text

```js
function closespan(val) {
  debugger;
  var parent = val.parentElement;
  parent.parentElement.removeChild(parent);
  var valHTML = document.getElementById("lblshowselected");
  var valSPLIT = valHTML.replace(/<img src="images\/delete.png" height="10">/, ",");
  valHTML.innerHTML(valSPLIT);
}
```

```html
<div runat="server" id="lblshowselected">
  <div class="tknz-token">A0100<span class="tknz-token-x" onclick="closespan(this);"><img src="images/delete.png" height="10"></span></div>
  <div class="tknz-token">A0102<span class="tknz-token-x" onclick="closespan(this);"><img src="images/delete.png" height="10"></span></div>
</div>
```